# AudioQueue | Change audio device while audioQueue is running

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, core-audio, audioqueue

i am using audio queue for playback and for record on OSX | Mac and have a use case,
Its something like, user may change the Audiodevice ( Input and output both ) while audio queue is running either for playback or for record,

This is what i have done so far,

```
OSStatus result = noErr;

// get the device list
AudioObjectPropertyAddress thePropertyAddress = { kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice, kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster };
UInt32 thePropSize;

CFStringRef theDeviceName;

// get the device name
thePropSize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
thePropertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioObjectPropertyName;
thePropertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
thePropertyAddress.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

// get the name of the device
result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( (AudioObjectID)input,
                                    &thePropertyAddress, 0, NULL, &thePropSize, &theDeviceName);

if ( result != noErr){
    log("Error while getting property");
    return;
}

// get the uid of the device
CFStringRef theDeviceUID;
thePropertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceUID;
result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData( (AudioObjectID)input,
                                    &thePropertyAddress, 0, NULL, &thePropSize, &theDeviceUID);

try{
    XThrowIfError(AudioQueueSetProperty(mQueue,kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentDevice,&theDeviceUID, sizeof(CFStringRef)),"set input device");
}
catch (CAXException e) {

    char buf[256];
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
}
```

but its throwing an exception **kAudioQueueErr_InvalidRunState** , [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117-CH5g-RCM0127)saying  its can't be done while queue is running;

Is there any other way  to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't any other way to achieve this (AudioQueue has too few functions at all). You need firstly to stop audio queue, then change its property, and finally start it again.